# Android Studio Debug How to view byte variable

Tags: android-studio, debugging, smali

I'm trying to debug a 3rd party app with an Android Studio.

When I'm at the smali code, `new-array v1, p1`, I want to access p1 value. When I evaluate p1, it says `p1 = byte[]@13648`. After `new-array v1, p1`, v1 is 35.

How can I see the content of p1?

[image]

Comment: You can try if [Smalidea plugin](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/wiki/smalidea) for Android Studio won't help you.

Comment: that's the plugin that I'm using to debug

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that. Well, I guess you need to dereference `p1` but I don't know how to specify it.

Comment: I would create an issue in the [smali repository](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali) and ask there.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the before and after states you describe?

Comment: added an image of what the p1 value looks like. If array length of p1 is 35, how can I access it to look at the individual array element?

Comment: What does it look like if you add it in the watches pane? I would expect it to be expandable, so that you can expand it and see all of the individual elements.

Comment: It still looks like the one in the picture. I don't see any arrow to expand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect its content after `clone()`.

[image]